# Javascript code to add HTML code to body tag

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I have a webpage which I am experimenting with, where the user has to have a specific bookmarklet from another one of my sites to continue the game. This bookmarklet adds code to the  tag, and enables the user to continue.

The problem is that I am having trouble making the bookmarklet, since I am fairly new at using javascript.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what did you try? what's blocking you?

Comment: If you're new to javascript try to learn it first: https://www.codeschool.com/paths/javascript This might help you.

Comment: @pataluc Not the bookmarklet itself, but rather what inputs the code in the body tag.

Comment: I'm confused. Your title appears that you need help with adding the HTML code but your question appears to ask for help with making the bookmarklet. Do you need help with JS to add HTML to the body or how to create a bookmarklet?

Comment: @mark Sorry for the confusion. I need help with JS to add HTML to the body.

Comment: @Doodlebunch Thanks for the link, I have not been able to find a website that teaches javascript well. I will try it.

Comment: Please do not down vote or add anymore answers, please. This question was from when I had no idea what I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add javascript to the body, try this:

```
var code = '<h1>TEST</h1>';
document.body.innerHTML = code;
```

You will have to play with it to get what you want to do, but that's the general idea. If you have a particular `div` you want to use, try doing the same thing but with `document.getElementById`